# Define a webHttpBinding object in C# (without config file)

Tags: wcf, webhttpbinding

I have to manually configure a ServiceReference in my project, because my project uses a secondary config file, and I’ve run into a lot of problems trying to read from that file.  I was able to get things working by manually defining a basicHttpBinding instance on my client as follows:

```
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding
{
    Name = "something",
    CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0),
    OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0),
    ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0),
    SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0),
    AllowCookies = false,
    //and so on...
};
```

However, I’m not able to make test calls to my web service via a browser, unless I change the server-side binding to webHttpBinding.  With webHttpBinding, browser-requests to my service return serialized data as expected.  But, requests from my clients fail because they are using basicHttpBinding.

How do I define a WebHttpBinding object instead of a BasicHttpBinding object?  I can’t find a constructor, even though one is listed in MSDN.

Comment: `WebHttpBinding` does have a constructor (it has a few); what do you mean you can't find one?

Comment: I mean I'm not able to write a similar chunk of code that says var binding = new WebHttpBinding... "WebHttpBinding" isn't a recognized class.  I am already using System.ServiceModel, so I don't know of any other needed reference.

Comment: Add reference to System.ServiceModel.Web.dll?

Comment: Alright, I didn't have that dll added in my References, so Intellisense wasn't even suggesting I add it to my using statements.  Please add an answer and I'll accept it.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `WebHttpBinding` is in the `System.ServiceModel.Web.dll` - you need to add a reference to it. In the future you can check the type's [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.webhttpbinding.aspx) for the assembly where it lives on.

Comment: Thanks.  I had checked the Namespace, but not the Assembly.